# Printer Drivers won't install on XP x64, printer is Kodak ESP Office 2170

Tags: windows-xp, 64-bit, printer

So I bought a printer yesterday and go to install it today and now I am at the "get the PC to talk wirelessly to the printer" step and can't seem to get through it.

Drivers downloaded from [here](http://support.en.kodak.ca/app/answers/detail/a_id/36460/selected/true) but I am getting error code 101-903.

[image]

I am running Windows XP x64 which is likely the issue.  Does anyone know if theres any tricky way to get around this and be able to print/scan without changing my OS.

Comment: Can you print wired? Or is any connection a problem?

Comment: @soandos - didn't get a USB cable but don't think it's a wireless issue, was able to put in wifi info on printer without issue and seems to be connected

Comment: No, I mean do you have any x64 drivers for this printer that work, and its just the wireless part that fails, or do you have nothing?

Comment: Did you get a driver disk with the printer?

Comment: @soandos - oh, no as soon as I open the driver installer exe I get that error, just there's a few steps like setting up the network details on the printer itself that worked fine

Comment: @Windos - yes I get the same error when I run setup.exe

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't be able to get around that in anyway, and if you did it probably wont work.However, I did have a look for a driver and found [this](http://support.en.kodak.com.au/app/answers/detail/a_id/38489/selected/true) driver that you could download of the Kodak website. I'm not sure if it will work but its worth a shot.